# Nothing shows under Summary on Dope Sheet and cannot insert keyframes, either - Blender 2.8 Beta

Tags: dopesheet

I had prepared everything, following a video-tutorial step by step, to do a little animation (with armature) of this 2D zombie character and when I go to dope sheet, nothing appears under Summary.

I don´t know what I´m doing wrong, what I´m not clicking or have clicked, what needs to be selected.

I have tried everything I can think of in my limited beginner stage, as well as looked for answers on the net to this specific problem and nothing works. Including a screen-shot in case you are able to see what the problem might be right away.

I can´t finish this learning project.

[image: Nothing Showing under Summary in Dope Sheet - Blender 2.8 Beta]

Comment: No worries, it was the silliest thing ever. One has to select the armature and then click on the viewport and press "i" on the keyboard. A drop-down menu appears to select the kind of animation and keyframe, and all the elements appear on the Dope Sheet then under Summary. This is what is like to be a complete newbie :D

Comment: I just figured this out myself literally 20 minutes ago, Blender UI will always be opaque, not even a hint while hovering mouse

Comment: Yep, Blender 2.8 seems a massive improvement in terms of UI but I still run into problems with the simplest tasks and processes. Maybe the newest stable version (not Beta) which I think is scheduled to be launched in July will be more user-friendly, fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Select the rig model by pressing A in your keyboard the rig will get highlighted in orange in blender 2.8.3 that means everything is selected. right click outside the model but in the same panel ex : 3DViewport. press "I" to insert keyframe. it works for blender 2.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this is what worked for me: In *Pose Mode*, select your bone in the *Outliner*, <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> some component of the transform and select *Insert Keyframes*.

[image]